# CSS: Right align a vertically rotated text

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-float

I can't seem to align a vertically rotated div all the way to the right side of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/F23W2/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="vertical">Vertical Text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    float: right;
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
}
```

- There is unwanted margin created between right page border and the div.
- Top part of rotated div gets cropped.

Although I can use negative margins to work around, I was wondering if a cleaner solution exists.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change the origin of the rotation transform via `transform-origin: 100% 100%;`

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.vertical {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  float: right;
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* FF3.5+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical">Vertical Text</div>
```

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F23W2/3/)

Comment: @ClintPachl Here is a way: http://jsfiddle.net/4078ggjg/. I'm sure there is a 'cleaner' way, but I didn't take the time to simplify the rotations, translations, and scaling.

Comment: That is some serious CSS-FU @BigMacAttack! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Using what you had, I came up with a cleaner way that works cross-browser (FF, Chrome, Safari) on Win (even IE11), OSX, iOS, and BSD: https://jsfiddle.net/yrfm5uec/1/